# AVAudioEngine & AVAudioPlayer. setVoiceProcessingEnabled low volume output

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, avaudioengine, sfspeechrecognizer

As the title suggests I am using AVAudioEngine for SFSpeechRecognition input & AVAudioPlayer for sound output.

Apple says in this [talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/510) that the setVoiceProcessingEnabled function very usefully cancels the output from speaker to the mic. I set voiceProcessing on the AVAudioInputNode and AVAudioOutputNode.

When running xcode when speechRecognitionEnabled:YES throws the following error:

```
throwing 18,446,744,073,709,551,615
  from AU (0x13bf98dd0): auou/vpio/appl, render err: 18,446,744,073,709,551,615
```

There is no error thrown when setting up the nodes and it seems to work however the volume is low, even when the system volume is turned up. Any solution to this would be much appreciated.

I tried various AVAudioEngine node setups. One setup with a mixer node and one without. I am expecting the audio levels to be loud, in conjunction with the system volume.

Comment: To get helpful answers, please show your code. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable voice processing on both the input and output nodes?

Here is what I tried and it worked (somewhat):

```
audioInputNode=engine.inputNode 
    audioInputNode.volume=0
    do{
        try audioInputNode.setVoiceProcessingEnabled(true)
    }
    catch{
        print("Could not enable voice processing in audioinputnode")
    }
    let outputNode = engine.outputNode
    do{
        try outputNode.setVoiceProcessingEnabled(true)
    }
    catch{
        print("Could not enable voice processing in output")
    }
```

I say worked "somewhat" because when I record the mic input, the sound from the speaker is definitely cancelled out, but the mic audio recorded to a file is a little choppy

Comment: And what happens if you set `setVoiceProcessingEnabled` on one of the input/output nodes only?

Comment: It only works when voice processing is enabled on both input and output. Doesn't work if it is enabled on just one of them. I think they also mentioned this in the WWDC 2019 session where they first unveiled voice processing. I didn't get a crash though, just the background sound didn't get cancelled.